# Delay between two functions of one method

Tags: java, android, delay

I am new to Android Studio. I want to put delay between Animation of button AND opening of second activity, So that animation runs and then splashActivity opens.

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Animation anim4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.splash_anim);
            btn.startAnimation(anim4);

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, splashActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you want to sleep?

Comment: You can use handler like this:Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
      public void run(){
        startRecord();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
   }
}, 5); inside your click listner.

Comment: `two functions of one method` makes no sense to me. A `method` **is** a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

int Delay_time_of_animation=500;

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){

```
Animation anim4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.splash_anim);
            btn.startAnimation(anim4);

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {

                          startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, splashActivity.class));
                      }
                  }, Delay_time_of_animation);

  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the native java Timer for the delay. if you want to delay between two method then you have to pass the delay time in milliseconds.

```
int DELAY_TIME=2000

    //start your animation
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
   //this code will run after the delay time which is 2 seconds.
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, splashActivity.class));
        }
    }, DELAY_TIME);
```

2000 millisecond means 2 second you can increase this time